# Некорректная работа метода sort() на Node v.8.1.3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сортировка

На входе есть массив

```
['1:nnn','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','2:uu','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:ff','1:ll','1:pp']
```

Необходимо задать компаратор в методе sort() таким образом, чтобы массив отсортировался по следующему принципам:

1) Сохранить первоначальную сортировку по длине элементов (не менять местами элементы разной длины, например элементы 1:nnn и 1:yy)

2) Если элементы одинаковой длины, то сравнивать первый символ каждого элемента, сначала должны идти элементы с префиксом 1, затем элементы с префиксом 2.

Я попытался написать следующий код, но не могу понять почему он не работает так, как хотелось бы на Node v.8.1.3? Некорректный результат, который я получаю, выглядит вот так:

```
['2:uu','1:nnn','1:ll','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','1:ff','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:pp']
```

Если запускать код в браузере или в стаковерфлоу, то я получаю ожидаемый результат

```
["1:nnn","1:vvv","2:zzz","1:yy","1:cc","1:ff","1:ll","1:pp","2:xx","2:uu","2:tt","2:qq","2:aa"]
```

В чём может быть проблема и что я делаю не так?

```js
let output=['1:nnn','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','2:uu','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:ff','1:ll','1:pp']

output.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.length===b.length) {
     if ((+a.slice(0,1))<(+b.slice(0,1))) return -1 
     else return 1
  } else return 0
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: У вас написано, что если элементы разной длины, то они равны о_О

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна симметричная сортировка, а не логическое значение для возврата только одного или двух значений.

Array#sort ожидает три значения, в зависимости от требуемого и заданного порядка, но ваш результат пропускает одно значение, которое может быть важным, в зависимости от реализации алгоритма сортировки.

Вместо этого вы можете вернуть дельту значений и получить идеально отсортированный результат, независимо от реализации алгоритма сортировки.

```js
let output=['1:nnn','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','2:uu','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:ff','1:ll','1:pp']

output.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length || a.split(':', 1) - b.split(':', 1));

console.log(output);
```